# Save joints coordinates (x,y,z) in a txt file Microsoft Kinect sdk v1.5

Tags: sdk, coordinates, kinect

I like to save de joints coordinates (x,y,z) in a text file, C# language, Microsoft Kinect v1.5.

I can now obtain the joint coordinates, my problem is how to pass it to a text file. Because when i create a loop i cant´t close the stream.

If anyone can help ill be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Kinect Toolbox - http://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/ - offers the ability to save any of the 3 streams to a file.

If you wish to role your own, the `Skeleton` object is a serializable object.  In each `SkeletonFrameReady` callback you can save the appropriate `Skeleton` to a `List` (or some other array type object) and then serialize the `List` to a file when you are ready to save it.